# How to add a target or tag in topic section in firebase console notifications?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I want to test the cordova-plugin-firebase, and send a notification with a topic, but when I enter firebase.com >> console >> my project >> notifications >> send message >> and I click on radio button topic, I can't find any target  (or tag) to add to the topic.
Anyone know how to add a topic?